# let $n$ is non-negative number so $n$ is the solution for the equation

Tags: linear-algebra

let $n$ is non-negative number
so the equations

-->$(x^2+1)^2+n = yz+1$

-->$(y^2+1)^2+n = zx+1$

-->$(z^2+1)^2+n = xy+1$

have $(x,y,z)$ real solution.

find all solutions for the non-negative n that make $(x,y,z)$ are real numbers
and find $(x,y,z)$ also

Comment: So, how much progress have you made on the question? Where do you get stuck? This is not a site for just dumping undigested questions with no effort on your part.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First argue why $x,y,z$ must have same sign. Now subtract any one equations from the other and conclude that $x=y=z$ is only possible solution. Substitute in anyone equation and find the solution.